# Linux HDD partition shows full. If live booted, contents add upto 13GB, but 235GB shows used by Gparted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, nautilus, out-of-memory

I am using Debian Wheezy, I get constant notifications: 0 bytes left (i cannot download anything, so notifications are not erraneous). Disk Usage Analyzer shows only 13.2GB of files. Gparted shows 224GB used and 54GB free (Root Partition). After I live booted with Ubuntu14.04, I checked the properties of the partition, which showed Total Contents:13GB only, but again Gparted gave same results. I have also encountered the nautilus bug, which caused the kcore file in /proc to show as 140.7TB. (reboot won't help at all).

Result of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          273G  220G   40G  85% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
/dev/sda2       273G  220G   40G  85% /
tmpfs           197M  728K  196M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           794M   84K  794M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sr0        456M  456M     0 100% /media/cdrom0
```

Comment: You need to give more information.  Edit your post to show the output of `df -h`.

Comment: @garethTheRed : done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:-

```
du -hxP <dir> | grep '[0-9]M'
```

to find files and folders that have a size in Megabytes.  It will take a long time to run.  The `x` option makes it stay on one file system (so that it doesn't try to add up /proc for example) therefore you'll need to run it against the mount point of each mounted partition that you wish to check.

Run it as `root` in order to get a more accurate result.

**Note:** It'll take a while to run!

Comment: Thanks a lot @garethTheRed, searched for G instead of M, got a 140GB x error file, not sure how it got generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`du ~ -H | sort -n -r| less`

It will show you the biggest files at the top and will sort by size all from your home folder.